# PHP inheritance issue

Tags: php

I googled for this for quite awhile. I think I am missing some big concept, but I can't figure out why this won't work

//SomeClass.php

```
class SomeClass 
{
    protected $something;
    public function __construct() {
        $this->something = 'password';
    }
    public function test() {
        return ($this->something);
    }
}
```

//OtherClass.php

```
require_once('SomeClass.php');
class OtherClass extends SomeClass
{   
    public function __construct() {
        echo parent::test();
    }
}
```

What is the deal here?

Comment: It just doesn't output anything. I would think it should output "password"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should call parent::__construct() before calling parent::test()

Comment: Right. Manual excerpt: `Note: Parent constructors are not called implicitly if the child class defines a constructor. In order to run a parent constructor, a call to parent::__construct() within the child constructor is required.`

Comment: ARGH!!!!!!! Thanks a ton! You're a champ. God bless you. I really should read the manual better, but it's a touch too boring.

Answer (score 0):

Constructor must not return any value.

Comment: Ya, sorry, that was a typo. I updated the answer and it still doesn't work.